# Storage Benchmark/Testing Solutions for FSX for Windows File Server

Tags: performance, storage, amazon-web-services, benchmarking, windows-server-2019

We have a PoC that we setup where we have Amazon FSX for Windows File Server connected to our DFS setup. This a rebuild of a previous PoC done by the previous team that was a disaster. Essentially throughput was sub-optimal causing our version builds to slow significantly.

Therefore, with this PoC we're trying to do our due diligence and test before pushing to our dev teams. Normally, tools like Crystal Disk Mark would be my go-to but they're aren't working in this specific situation. I was wondering if anyone would have a tool that would work on the solution I described above. Our main concern, at least at this phase, is throughput but the more metrics we can test the better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `diskspd` suitable? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/manage/diskspd-overview

Comment: That's why I'm here you're supposed to tell me lol. I saw this tool before posting this question but wasn't sure if it would be effective. Let me try it out and if it provides results I'll let you know so you can put the answer in.